# How do I truncate lines when printing in emacs?

Tags: emacs, printing, word-wrap, truncate

When I print from emacs, I want it to truncate (not wrap) lines that are too long for the paper. I can't seem to get it to do this.

Note that I have my emacs display(!) truncating the lines but when I print, it wraps the lines.

Answer (score 0):

One crude way would be to manually truncate long lines, maybe with a keyboard macro:

```
C-x (              ; Start recording macro
C-u 20             ; Prefix command for move-to-column
M-x move-to-column ; Move cursor to 20th column
C-space            ; Set mark
C-e                ; Move to end of line
C-w                ; ..and remove everything (truncating line)
C-a                ; Move to start of line
C-n                ; ..and to next line, read to repeat
C-x )              ; End macro
C-x e              ; Apply macro to next line
```